# Search Param/Query for LinkedIn Companies based on industry

Tags: search, linkedin-api

I'm wondering please if anyone knows a way of searching LinkedIn companies based on industry, i.e. 'media production'?

From this page here - https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/

I remember in the old days they used to have a search function, but seem to have removed it? Now you can only search by keyword which is pretty useless.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this via the API. LinkedIn marketing API provides an Organization Search API for this use case.

You can search using just keywords by calling the search API.

eg:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search?q=companiesV2&baseSearchParams.keywords=LinkedIn%20Corporation`

However, if you happen to know information like the company's region/industry/company size etc. you can specify those as facets (think of these like filters)

eg:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search?q=companiesV2&baseSearchParams.keywords=LinkedIn%20Corporation&companySearchParams.facetIndustry%5B0%5D=6&companySearchParams.facetCompanySize%5B0%5D=H&companySearchParams.facetCompanyCountryRegion%5B0%5D=us:84`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-search